# PHP or JQuery or CSS (in wordpress)- Show Div when Table data is displayed

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am using the Flexible Map plugin on a wordpress site. The plugin has a form that allows the user to enter their 'from address' to get directions to the location displayed on the map. The form does not have an ID or class (and I am not able to add one).

I would like the user to be able to print the directions once the form is submitted, but I don't want the print button to show up until after the directions have displayed from the user pressing the submit button.

The directions are displayed in a table, so I was thinking I could use JQuery to say that when the table is displayed, then show the print div.

I'm thinking it's something like this, but I'm not sure how to format it based on a table (because the form does not have an ID):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('#idOfYourForm').on("submit", function () {
$('#print').show();
});
});
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

**EDIT** Here is the code that is generated once the directions submit button is pressed:

```
<div id="my-dir-div" style="float: left; direction: ltr;">
<form>
<p>
<input type="text" name="from">
<input type="submit" value="Get Directions">
</p>
</form>
<div jstcache="0">
<div class="adp-warnbox" jsdisplay="warnings.length" jstcache="1" style="display: none;">
<div class="warnbox-c2" jstcache="0"></div>
<div class="warnbox-c1" jstcache="0"></div>
<div class="warnbox-content" jscontent="$this" jsselect="warnings" jstcache="5"></div>
<div class="warnbox-c1" jstcache="0"></div>
<div class="warnbox-c2" jstcache="0"></div>
</div>
<div jseval="setupPanelStep(this, $waypointIndex)" jsvalues="$waypointIndex:0;" jsselect="legs[0].start_address" jstcache="2">
<table id="adp-placemark" class="adp-placemark" jstcache="0">
<tbody jstcache="0">
<tr jstcache="0">
<td jstcache="0">
<img jsvalues=".src:markerIconPaths[$waypointIndex]" jstcache="14" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/icon_greenA.png">
</td>
<td class="adp-text" jscontent="$this" jstcache="12">211 South Elson Street, Kirksville, MO 63501, USA</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div jsvalues="$legIndex:$index;" jsselect="legs" jstcache="3" jsinstance="*0">
<div class="adp-legal" jscontent="copyrights" jstcache="4">Map data ©2013 Google</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="print">
<input id="print" class="printbtn" type="button" value="Print Directions" onclick="return pop_print()">
<script type="text/javascript">
function pop_print(){
w=window.open(null, 'Print_Page', 'scrollbars=yes');
w.document.write(jQuery('div#my-dir-div').html());
w.document.close();
w.print();
}
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this (only if the table with id `adp-placemark` is available on the page then show it)

```
$(function(){
    if($('#my-dir-div table#adp-placemark').length) $('#print').show();
});
```

Or, this one

```
$(function(){
    if($('#my-dir-div table#adp-placemark td.adp-text').length) $('#print').show();
});
```

Comment: I tried both, inserted directly into the page like     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $(function(){
    if($('#my-dir-div table#adp-placemark td.adp-text').length) $('#print').show();
});
}); but neither worked.

Comment: Actually `$(function(){...})` is short hand of `jQuery(document).ready()`, so use one.

Comment: You may keep the code `if($('#my-dir-div table#adp-placemark').length) $('#print').show();` just under the `function pop_print(){...}` inside your `<script>`.

Comment: I removed the script from the page and added it in the function pop_print like so, but it didn't work.. maybe I did something wrong.    <script type='text/javascript'>
 function pop_print(){
  if($('#my-dir-div table#adp-placemark').length) $('#print').show();
  w=window.open(null, 'Print_Page', 'scrollbars=yes');
  w.document.write(jQuery('$target_element').html());
  w.document.close();
  w.print();
 }
 </script>

Comment: The pop_print is a plugin, it's under the div: '<div id="my-dir-div" style="float:left;">
<form>
<p>
<input type="text" name="from">
<input type="submit" value="Get Directions">
</p>
</form>
</div>
<div id="print">
<input id="print" class="printbtn" type="button" value="Print Directions" onclick="return pop_print()">
<script type="text/javascript">
function pop_print(){
if($('#my-dir-div table#adp-placemark').length) $('#print').show();
w=window.open(null, 'Print_Page', 'scrollbars=yes');
w.document.write(jQuery('div#my-dir-div').html());
w.document.close();
w.print();
}
</script>
</div>'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29334/discussion-between-user1172854-and-sheikh-heera)

Comment: Then keep the code right before the closing body `</body>` tag as given in the example, as it this.